# VB6 and ASP - any difference between Application.Value() and Application.Contents.Item()?

Tags: vb6, asp-classic

I'm trying to debug some old code in a VB6 application called from an ASP page.  At a certain point in the page life cycle, I'm getting an "Object not set" error for either

`ASPTypeLibrary.ScriptingContext.Application.Contents.Item` or `ASPTypeLibrary.ScriptingContext.Session.Contents.Item`

I notice that some other code in the function uses Application.Value() to get values, and does not seem to be subject to the same problem. Is there a difference between `.Value` and `.Contents.Item` ?  Different error handling, perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean:

```
Application("variable")
```

vs.

```
Application.Contents(x)
```

? To my knowledge neither `Application.Value()` or `Application.Contents.Item()` is correct, but please correct me if I misunderstood something.

If my assumption is correct, `Application("variable")` simply gets or set a specific Application variable, whereas `Application.Contents` is a collection which contains all Application variables, and if your index into this is out of bounds you'll get an error.